# Assert HttpBadRequest in ASP.NET Web API unit test

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm testing the *type* of the response from a WebAPI controller. I can find both `HttpNotFoundResult` as well as `HttpOkObjectResult` but **nothing** similar to `HttpBadRequestResult`. How do I assert this?

Answer (score 0):

It was called `BadRequestResult`.

*It seems like they're renaming the result types if you look the [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core) page. `HttpNotFoundResult` is now `NotFoundResult` for example.*

UPDATE: Confirmed that they're renaming the return types to excluding *Http* in the return types. See this guide for reference: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html